# Laravel pagination does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

When I return something like `UserConversations::paginate(10)` with API.

Lets say I have array of conversations objects:

```
let conversations = []
let moreLink = null
```

after API callback I have

```
conversations = [...conversations, ...response.data.data]
moreLink = response.data.links.next
```

Lets assume that `moreLink = '/conversations?page=2'`

Now in meantime if I get new conversation within database one conversation is pushed from `page=1` to `page=2` where from response I get duplication...

The best way I see to get around this is to check is any of `page=2` conversation `ID's` already within `conversation array` and to not include it if it is..

Is there a better way to use this in case someone loads up to 100 conversations per request? It needs to go in for loop on client side just if there is one duplication.

There would be another way if sorting before pagination was done just by ID..
So I could send within request the biggest ID within conversations and to return next page from that id, but mine are not sorted by id.

Comment: the pagination method allows you to pass the page number as the second argument, you should be able to return the data you need with the page number.

Comment: please read my question again, passing pagee number has nothing to do with this

Comment: if you have timestamps on your models, you could consider using a timestamp to prevent newer data from appearing.

Comment: give example I dont know what do you mean

Comment: so, ```UserConversations::where('created_at', '<', $datetime)->paginate(10);``` where ```$datetime``` remains constant throughout the pagination process. Meaning any entries created after the pagination started would fall outside of this range.

Comment: In that case I would need to set datetime on create and then use it if query page exists on request. It would work but I would need to pass datetime, set datetime and save it somewhere. But it would work, post it as answer I will wait to see other answers

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to order it by something like id's? then you would always have the same order and therefor nothing would be moved? this problem thou seems very edge case.

Comment: even when I do order by id it still pushes another one or as many as they are added into database onto next link when its used